# sqlite3: Create tables with many rows or one table with more columns

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm asking for a best practive when creating some tables for localization of an Web Interface in sqlite3

In my first intetion I wanted to create a table with the different languages, and another on for the Messeage Code and Entries.

tblLanguage

```
+------------+-------------+---------+
| idLangCode | txtLangName | txtCode |
+------------+-------------+---------+
|          1 | English     | en      |
|          2 | German      | de      |
|          3 | French      | fr      |
|          4 | Spanish     | es      |
|          5 | Chinese     | zh      |
+------------+-------------+---------+
```

tblMessageText

```
+----+-------+--------------------------+------------+
| Id | Code  |         Message          | LanguageID |
+----+-------+--------------------------+------------+
|  1 | 20500 | Set Point changed        |          1 |
|  2 | 20500 | Sollwert geändert        |          2 |
|  3 | 20500 | Punto de ajuste cambiado |          5 |
+----+-------+--------------------------+------------+
```

So in the second table I would have several rows with the same Message Code but whith an different language text.

The other possibility would be to have just one table with just one row for each Message Code but an Column for each language.

tblMessageTextMulti

```
+----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+
| id | Code  | txtMessageText_EN | txtMessageText_DE |    txtMessageText_ES     |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | 20500 | Set Point changed | Sollwert geändert | Punto de ajuste cambiado |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+
```

My team likes the second solution with just one table more, because it just has one entry for each Message Code, and you see all Language text side by side.

What I like on the first solution is, that I could dynmically Query the langugage with just on line in php:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM qryInfoMessage WHERE idLangCode=' .$Language;
```

For the second solution with one table I can not store the query itself in the database, because I have to change the Column name in my query dynmically. So I have to put this together in php.

```
$query = 'SELECT Code,  txtMessageText_EN FROM tblMessageTextMulti;
```

What I dont show here is that my query is much more complex, whith string substitution and date time conversion.

*Beside that, what are the advantages or disadvantages of this solutions. Which one should be more perfomant and what is the best practice?*

Comment: I don't like the second solution at all, because every time you add a new language the structure of the table has to change.  On the other hand, if you want to add support for a new language using the first approach you need only add more data; the existing records do not need to be modified in any way.

Comment: I strongly agree with Tim, and I just add that option 2 would make easier an analysis that's not what these tables are meant for (showing all languages versions of the same message side by side). I would say option 1 is best practice in most cases, including yours.

Comment: What I encountered that the second solution with one table is around 25 % faster than the first solution.